# Python's pyalsa module does not show updated alsa status (volume, mute, etc.)

Tags: python, linux, alsa

I am using the `pyalsa` module from [alsa's website](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page). I can set the volume, toggle the switch, but couldn't get new volume after changing it externally with e.g., amixer. The same for mute status (`get_switch`, if I am not wrong).

What is wrong? Should I use `pyalsa` this way?

```py
from pyalsa import alsamixer
mixer = alsamixer.Mixer()
mixer.attach()
mixer.load()
alsa = alsamixer.Element(mixer, 'Master')

print(alsa.get_volume())  # shows e.g., 15729 (max 65536)
# run shell command `amixer set Master 50%`, the volume actually changes
print(alsa.get_volume())  # still shows 15729
alsa.set_volume_all(30000)  # the volume also changes
print(alsa.get_volume())  # shows 30000
```

Edit: I find the `pyalsaaudio` module also behaves like this.

Answer (score 0):

`pyalsa` will not handle waiting mixer events automatically, one has to use `Mixer.handle_events(...)`:

```
# change volume externally, e.g., with amixer command
mixer.handle_events()
alsa.get_volume()  # returns the new value
```